# LeanFT WPF testing: What is "FlightGuiSampleWpfApp()" in the Flight GUI Sample WPF App testing code sample?

Tags: c#, wpf, leanft, uft14

I am trying to use LeanFT to test the Flight GUI WPF app that comes with UFT.  MicroFocus has provided the code to do this at the location below

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_.NET/CodeEx.NETWPF.htm

Howevere, there is a mention of  FlightGuiSampleWpfApp()) in the code as shown below

```
using (new FlightGuiSampleWpfApp()) {
```

I can not find where  FlightGuiSampleWpfApp() (class?) is  defined. I think it holds the code to launch the Flight GUI app (HPE MyFlight Sample Application).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in their documentation. Indeed there is no such class defined.

You can create one yourself using (for example) [`Desktop.LaunchAut` API](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_.NET/LaunchAUT_Samples.htm)

So instead of that `using` statement, just do something like

```
[Test]
public void TestAutFullPath()
{
    IAut flightsgui= Desktop.LaunchAut("flightsgui");
    _flightGUIAapplicationWindow = Desktop.Describe<IWindow>(new WindowDescription
    {
        ObjectName = @"HP MyFlight Sample Application",
        FullType = @"window",
        WindowTitleRegExp = @"HP MyFlight Sample Application"
    });

    PerformLogin();
    SearchForFlight();
    OpenFlightsTable();
    SelectFlight();
    FinishOrder();
    VerifyOrderCompleted();

    flightsgui.Close();
}
```

Comment: I followed the example and created a whitelist file   C:\Users\Burak\AppData\Local\Hewlett-Packard\LeanFT\config\autconfig.json  
with this configuration
   {
    "allowedAuts": [
    {
            "fileName": "FlightsGUI.exe",
   "args": [],
   "workingDirectory": "C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\samples\Flights Application"
    }
  ]
}
and added this code

Comment: IAut flightsgui = Desktop.LaunchAut("FlightsGUI.exe");
but when I ran it, I got this error
HP.LFT.SDK.GeneralLeanFtException : AUT launch is not allowed. Verify that the AUT is configured in autConfig.json.

Comment: fileName=FlightsGUI.exe, args=[undefined], workingDirectory=undefined

Comment: file name is case sensitive. you wrote `autconfig.json` not `autConfig.json` as you used

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The a actual file on the computer is autConfig.json

Comment: autConfig.json is not configured correctly. It’s used with only one param and configured with 3. You’d be better of not configuring args and working directory in autConfig.json, and providing full path both in json and in code

Comment: That error says you didn’t configure the autConfig.json as you are using it. It’s hard to follow why through these comments. Try editing the question or better yet post a new one for this very issue